# Windows 7 and ExpanDrive permissions

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and using [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/), which creates what appears to be a removable storage device in my computer with data from a remote server. For example, I can add an S3 server as drive `Z:`.

How do I forbid access to this drive for some local users? There is no "Security" tab in the Properties dialog.